# How to assign jQuery click events for the third click?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, click, jquery-events

I'm trying to find a simple way to attach click events to an element, which is quite easy for the 1st and 2nd click events.. But, what I am trying to accomplish is a three click Toggle.

1st click = addClas('one');
2nd click = removeClass('one').addClass('two');
3rd click = removeClass('two').addClass('three');
next click would == 1st click and through the loop again..

I'm using a simple div and applying styling through CSS, to change the elements background position - all pretty typical and easy.. and is cake to do for a toggle() or click() event.. but I can't figure out for the life of me how to handle the 3rd click ! :D

Here is my markup, for example purposes:

```
<div class="tri-swtich" id="switch"></div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated !!

**UPDATE:**
I've got something that works.. but, IMHO it's ugly and messy.. there's got to be a cleaner, more concise way of doing this:

```
$(".tri_switch").click(function(){
    var this_id = $(this).attr("id");

    if( $(this).hasClass("one") ){                  
        $("input#user_"+this_id).attr('checked','checked');
        $("input.tri_switch_radio").not("#user_"+this_id).removeAttr('checked');
        $(this).removeClass('one').addClass('two');
        $("span.tri_switch_checked").text('User');
    }
    else if ( $(this).hasClass("two") ){
        $("input#admin_"+this_id).attr('checked','checked');
        $("input.tri_switch_radio").not("#admin_"+this_id).removeAttr('checked');
        $(this).removeClass('two').addClass('three');
        $("span.tri_switch_checked").text('Admin');

    }
    else if ( $(this).hasClass("three") ){
        $("input#readonly_"+this_id).attr('checked','checked');
        $("input.tri_switch_radio").not("#readonly_"+this_id).removeAttr('checked');
        $(this).removeClass('three').addClass('one');
        $("span.tri_switch_checked").text('Readonly');

    }
//  alert(this_id);
});
```

Comment: I have even thought about incrementing a count value, and resetting it on the 3rd click LOL.. I'm open to anything that makes this work, as long as its 'clean coding' :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yup @Codler, toggle() can take more than the default two parameters. Just throw in the third parameter:

```
$('#element').toggle(function(){
  $(this).addClass('one');
},
function(){
  $(this).removeClass('one').addClass('two');
},
function(){
  $(this).removeClass('two').addClass('three');
});
```

Comment: B E A U T I F U L ! I thought I had seen a case where someone used toggle() with a third parameter,.. but after searching and finding nothing on it, I chalked it up to bar recollection LOL 
Thanks, this will work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

```
var counter = 0;
$(".button").bind("click",function(){
    counter++;
    switch(counter){
        case 1:
            doSomething();
            break;
        case 2:
            doSomething2();
            break;
        case3:
            doSomething(3);
            counter=0;
            break;
    }
})
```

is it what you looking for?

Comment: in the last case.. did you mean 'case 3' or 'case3' as you typed?
Also, in that same case.. you have doSomething(3);
should that be doSomething3(); ??

Just want to make sure I clearly understand your example.. that I'm not missing something. Thanks

Comment: its my typo, sorry.
case 3 and doSomething3(). in every case, you can call some functions. just you need to reset the counter your last case. (in this example 3)

Answer (score 0):

Just implemented something on J QUERY. You can modify this code to fit your needs.

```
(function($)
{ var defaults = {
    threshold: 1000, // ms
}

function tripleHandler(event)
{
    var $elem = jQuery(this);

    settings = jQuery.extend({}, defaults, event.data);

    var clicks = $elem.data("triclick_clicks") || 0;
    var start  = $elem.data("triclick_start")  || 0;

    if (clicks === 0) { start = event.timeStamp; }

    if (start != 0
        && event.timeStamp > start + settings.threshold)
    {
        clicks = 0;
        start  = event.timeStamp;
    }

    clicks += 1;
    if (clicks === 3)
    {
        clicks     = 0;
        start      = 0;
        event.type = "tripleclick";

        if (jQuery.event.handle === undefined) {
            jQuery.event.dispatch.apply(this, arguments);
        }
        else {
            jQuery.event.handle.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    }

    $elem.data("triclick_clicks", clicks);
    $elem.data("triclick_start",  start);
}

var tripleclick = $.event.special.tripleclick =
{
    setup: function(data, namespaces)
    {
        $(this).bind("touchstart click.triple", data, tripleHandler);
    },
    teardown: function(namespaces)
    {
        $(this).unbind("touchstart click.triple", tripleHandler);
    }
};
})(jQuery);

$("#password").on("tripleclick", function() { 
//console.log('Tripple clicked password'); 
    if ('password' == $('#password').attr('type')) {
       $('#password').prop('type', 'text');
    } else {
        $('#password').prop('type', 'password');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
<div class="one" id="clickarea">click me</div>
$('#clickarea').click(function(){
  if($( "#clickarea" ).hasClass('one')){
   $(this).removeClass('one').addClass('two');
  }else if($( ".hoverarea" ).hasClass('two')){
   $(this).removeClass('two').addClass('three');
}else{
$(this).removeClass('three').addClass('one');
}
```

```html
<div class="one" id="clickarea">click me</div>
```